# Keep parent from scrolling while iframe has focus

Tags: iframe

I want to keep the parent from scrolling when using the mouse wheel while focused on the iframe.  This only happens when the iframe scrolling limit has been reached.  Its so annoying.  I have found similar Q&A, but not with the mouse wheel.  The scroll bars do not cause the parent to scroll, only the mouse wheel.

Comment: Do you have control over code inside iframe? Or there is some external website loaded?

Comment: Yes, I have control of the code inside iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set handler on 'wheel' and 'mousewheel' events in iframe. Inside event handler you should determine direction of wheeling  and if top or bottom of page is reached (depends on direction) - cancel default action for event.

jQuery pseudo-code:

```
$(document).on('wheel mousewheel', function(e) {
  var direction = getWheelDirection();


  if ( direction == 'bottom' ) {
    if ( ...bottom of page reached... ) return false;
  } else {
    if ( ...top of page reached... ) return false;
  }

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could set "hover" handler on iframe and toggle body "overflow" property.